# npm install not running package "install" script

Tags: node.js, npm

when I run `npm install <package>`, it seems the "install" script is not run after package install, such as `puppeteer, @sentry/cli`

```
npm i puppeteer

added 58 packages in 7s
```

normally, it should download a chromium binary after the package install, but nothing happened.

I don't think I set some special config in `.npmrc`

```
npm config list

; "global" config from /Users/lixiaokai/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/etc/npmrc

ignore-scripts = false

; "user" config from /Users/lixiaokai/.npmrc

//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken = (protected)
canvas_binary_host_mirror = "https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node-canvas-prebuilt/"
chromedriver_cdnurl = "https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver"
electron_mirror = "https://cdn.npm.taobao.org/dist/electron/"
fse_binary_host_mirror = "https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/fsevents/"
phantomjs_cdnurl = "https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/phantomjs"
puppeteer_download_host = "https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors"
registry = "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/"
sass_binary_site = "http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node-sass"
sharp_libvips_binary_host = "https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/sharp-libvips"

; node bin location = /Users/lixiaokai/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin/node
; cwd = /Users/lixiaokai/code/test
; HOME = /Users/lixiaokai
; Run `npm config ls -l` to show all defaults.
```

npm versoin 7.16.0
node version 12.22.1
nvm version 0.38.0

the reason why I updated my npm version is when I try to stop `npm start` script, it throw an error

-debug.log:

```
10 silly lifecycle mobile-tiku@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '-c', 'umi dev' ]
11 silly lifecycle mobile-tiku@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle mobile-tiku@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: mobile-tiku@0.0.1 start: `umi dev`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/lixiaokai/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/lixiaokai/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1022:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
```

Comment: hm, Node 12 doesn't come with npm 7, though? It comes with npm 6, so that's already something you probably want to explain. The first version of Node that comes with npm 7 is v16.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you are right, man, I update npm to latest after I install node >0<

Comment: Why would you do that? npm versions are pretty much tailored to the node version they are bundled with. If you need a newer npm, update to the version of node that comes with that version of npm.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I updated my npm version because it throws an error when using `ctrl+c` to stop npm scripts (npm start mostly) in some projects

Comment: again: why update _npm_ instead of updating node, which automatically updates npm too. They go hand in hand, updating npm independent of node is very much not recommended.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans reply again: I'm working with a legacy project which only works with node 12 somehow, after downgrading my node, the npm issue arise, updating npm was the first thing that came into my head O_o

Comment: then I would strongly recommend leaving the original node+npm combo, and solving _that_ problem instead, because I've never had npm scripts have problems with ctrl-c, so it's entirely likely that if you do, that's not actually because of npm itself. Roll back to the version that comes with the version of node you need to use: does the install behaviour your post talks about still happen? If not, stick with that, and see if SO can help you (and: maybe it already has) with the ctrl-c issue.